# Ruby virtual machine

Tags: ruby

What is Ruby virtual machine?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a virtual machine that runs Ruby...

Comment: Are you asking about the Ruby Virtual Machine, or are you meaning to ask about ruby version manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ruby virtual machine is a ruby compiler.  Ruby runs in a virtual machine and I (think) compiles in it too.  There is a slight overhead when running ruby scripts because of this machine.

Comment: Any way to speed up Ruby scripts? May be a compiler to a native executable file format.

Answer (score 1):

A ruby virtual machine is a virtual machine (program) that executes ruby code. Usually a ruby interpreter.

In general virtual machines are machines implemented in software (though sometimes with hardware support).

For higher level object oriented languages (ruby,python,smalltalk .. ), that are very dynamic, compilation to a static language like c is impossible. So they are either completely interpreted, or compiled to an intermediate virtual machine instruction set, which is then interpreted.